# grep recursive filename matching (grep -ir "xyz" *.cpp) does not work

Tags: grep

while 
grep -ir "xyz" * recursively searches through the directories and tell me that the text is present in ./x/y/z/abc.cpp 
However ,
grep -ir "xyz" *.cpp offers no result. 
Isn't the second command supposed to recursively grep all cpp files inside the directory ? 
What am I missing here?

Comment: `*` expands to all the directories and files in your current directory, hence `grep` was able to find the string. `*.cpp` only greps from files and directories that matches the pattern `*.cpp`, directory `x` does not match glob `*.cpp`, hence grep didn't try to search in there.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Grep will recurse through any directories you match with your glob pattern. (In your case, you probably do not have any directories that match the pattern "*.cpp") You could explicitly specify them: `grep -ir "xyz" *.cpp */*.cpp */*/*.cpp */*/*/*.cpp`, etc. You can also use the --include option (see the example below)

If you are using GNU grep, then you can use the following:

```
grep -ir --include "*.cpp" "xyz" .
```

The command above says to search recursively starting in current directory ignoring case on the pattern and to only search in files that match the glob pattern "*.cpp".

**OR** if you are on some other Unix platform, you can use this:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.cpp" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i "xyz"
```

If you are sure that none of your files have spaces in their names, you can omit the `-print0` argument to find and the `-0` to xargs

The command above says the following: find all files (-type f) under the current directory (./) that match the name glob/wildcard "*.cpp" (-name "*.cpp") and then print them out delimited by a null (-print0). That list of files found should be written to the stdin of the next command: xargs.  xargs should read from stdin (default behavior) and split its input on nulls (-0) and then call the grep command with the specified options (grep -i "xyz") on that list of files.

If you are interested in learning more about why `grep -ir "xyz" *.cpp` does not work the way you think it should, you should search for "shell globbing" ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) is a good first article on the subject). I'll also try to provide a quick explanation. When you type in the command `grep -ir "xyz" *.cpp` and hit enter, there are two programs that are involved in executing your command. The first program is your shell (and unless you've done something to customize things, you are probably usually the bash shell - if you've never heard of a shell or bash, that's where you should start looking, there are tons of good articles). Suffice it say that a shell is just a program that is designed to let you navigate the filesystem on your computer and run other programs. (In Windows, when you double click on an icon to launch a program, or open a folder to access a file, the program that you are running is explorer.exe and it is the Windows graphical shell). So, when you type the command `grep -ir "xyz" *.cpp`, before grep is run, the shell handles reading your command and does a few things. One of the things is does is expand glob patterns (things like `*.txt` or `[0-9]+.pdf`). Like I said, if you want to understand it, go read more about it, but the thing you should take away is that the grep command never sees the `*.cpp`. What happens is, the shell looks in the current directory for any files or directories with a name that match the pattern `*.cpp` and then replaces them on the command line BEFORE it runs the grep command. (If it doesn't find anything that matches, then it will leave the `*.cpp` there and grep will see it, but grep because doesn't normally do glob matching, this doesn't do anything for you).

Alternatively, when you type in `grep -ir "xyz" *`, what happens is that the shell replaces the `*` with the name of every file and directory in the current directory (because `*` matches anything). Let's say you had a directory that contained file1, file2, and dir1, and dir2, then the shell would perform its replacements and then execute a command that looked like this `grep -ir "xyz" file1 file2 dir1 dir2`, which means grep would search file1 and file2 for a line with the string xyz, and because of the `-ir` it also search recursively through dir1 and dir2 and search any files found for that string as well. Lastly, if you've followed everything I've said so far, then it will make sense to you that grep does have a way to use glob patterns on recursive searches, and that is to use the `--include` option, as in the command I described earlier: `grep -ir --include "*.cpp" "xyz" .`, and the reason why we put the `*.cpp` in quotes in that command is to prevent the shell from trying to expand the glob pattern before we run the command.

Comment: sure. but why does grep -ir "xyz" *.cpp not work while grep -ir "xyz" * works?

Comment: I've updated the answer: grep will only recurse through any directories you specify on the command line. it does not do recursive filename matching.

Comment: Recursive filename matching is what the `--include` option is for.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks, I've updated the answer for GNU grep. I couldn't remember if there was an include option or not. I work in a multi-Unix environment and knew the find option off the top of my head.

Comment: That's not "why". "Why" is because whoever wrote grep didn't put in the effort to reasonably implement an exceedingly common use case.  There is absolutely no reason why the author of grep could not have written it so that "-R *.cpp " recursed over directories matching "*".  Absolutely nobody wants the current behavior.

Comment: @RobinDavies - I can see where you are coming from, but that's not really correct or fair to the Unix philosophy of tool development. Grep wasn't intended to deal with finding files to operate on, that was the job of other utilities and it was easy to chain them together and get complex things done. I'm not saying you are wrong for wanting it, I'm saying, that it's not fair to act like the designer of grep didn't understand what his program needed to do, and your last statement is just incorrect, as I like the tool as written and it's hard for me to believe that I'm the only one.

Comment: So why is it that  "find -name "\*.cpp" can do the right thing, but "grep -R "\*.cpp" could not?